# The best way to set material/model HDPE plate?

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials

i have a question. I need to model HDPE plate material and then few products made from it (pictures lower). It shoud be a visualisation of small play ground. It doesn't have to be 100% realistic look, but it shoud be modern looking and fresh. My problem is that I don't know how to do it the best way...[image]

My question has two parts:
1) modelling - the edge has to be curved. Is it better to only with texture (some normal map on the edge?) or shoud I model it - if so, how? Is there some function for that?

2) Texturing - how to setup the material to look it realistics? The real material has three layers - the edge shoudl be multiple colours - again is it easier to make it throug texture, or some other way?

Thanks for your help guys, I am not very skilled in Blender and now I find out that I really don't know how to handle this.

[image: problem]

Answer (score 0):

1- You should model it, this is called beveling (bevel modifier or CTRL+B with edge selected)

2- Through texture is the best way, either with face loops and face assigning different material or with one material for the whole mesh and a node system with gradients, mapping node, and very contrasted ramps.

This is a cool project and an easy model but you'll have some trouble if you don't study subdivision surface modeling and some common modifiers (solidify, bevel, mirror...). This is typically a 'hard surface' model, might want to do some googling with theses key terms to learn a bit more about modeling in Blender. For more specific questions stack exchange will be there for you though :)